# ReactJS: Login page shows whenever I refresh the page when im logged in

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, single-sign-on, google-signin

I'm trying to make a simple SSO login react app using react-google-login. Everything is working fine and I can login alright but whenever I'm logged in and I refresh the page, I can see my Login page for a split second before redirecting me back to the home page which is only accessible when a user is logged in. I want my app to persist its logged in state even when I refresh because it seems that it takes a split second for it to read if someone is logged in that's why it shows the login page for a split second. Any help and suggestions are greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Here's my App.js

```
function App() {
  const [accToken, setAccToken] = useState();
  const [loggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState(false)

  
  
  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(localStorage.getItem('accToken'))
      if(localStorage.getItem('accToken') !== null && localStorage.getItem('accToken') === `"${accToken}"`){
        setLoggedIn(true)
      }
      else{
        setLoggedIn(false)
      }
      }, 50);
  }
  , [accToken])
  
  

  
  return (
    <div>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route exact path="/login" element={loggedIn ? <Navigate replace to={"/"}/>:<Login setLoggedIn={setLoggedIn} setAccToken={setAccToken} accToken={accToken}/>}/>

          {
            loggedIn ?

            [
            <Route path="/" element={<SearchBar setLoggedIn={setLoggedIn} accToken={accToken} setAccToken={setAccToken}/>}/>,
            <Route path="/searched" element={<Table/>}/>
          ]
          :
          null
          }
          <Route path={"*"} element={ <Navigate replace to={ "/login" }/> }/>

        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
      
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

here's my Login.js

```
export default function Login({setLoggedIn, setAccToken, accToken}) {
    let navigate = useNavigate()
    const clientId = "clientID"
    const onLoginSuccess = (res) =>{
        console.log("Login Success:", res);
        setAccToken(res.tokenObj.access_token)
        navigate(`/`)
        localStorage.setItem('accToken', JSON.stringify(res.tokenObj.access_token))
    }
    const onLoginFailure = (res)=>{
        console.log("Login Failed:", res)
    }
    return (
        <div>
             Login Page <br/>
            <Link to="/">
                <button>button</button>
            </Link>
            <GoogleLogin
                clientId={clientId}
                buttonText="Login"
                onSuccess={onLoginSuccess}
                onFailure={onLoginFailure}
                cookiePolicy={"single_host_origin"}
                isSignedIn={true}
            />
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: why are you using a setTimeout in the useEffect in App.js?

Comment: @benmneb because my localStorage statements doesnt work without them, it doesnt update my states properly and causes my web to loop infinitely.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be happening because the initial value of the state "loggedIn" is false.
Add a function in useState of loggedIn which returns true or false depending if access token is present or not.

Comment: I've set the initial state of loggedIn to true and when I refresh the page, login page still shows up for a brief second.

Comment: @singhsterabhi was a solution found for this problem?? I've run into this same problem now. Please assist.

Answer (score 0):

It also happens to me. My workaround is putting a loading state with setTimeout to avoid showing the login page upon refreshing.